# MVC4 Force Mobile Site for all requests including Desktop

Tags: c#, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an MVC 4 Internet Application project for both Mobile and Desktop devices.
Now I want to just display the Mobile site globally for all browsers.

I've been trying to use the code `HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile)` to do this, but it doesn't seem to work correctly no matter where I put it.

Currently I can switch from the desktop site to the mobile site using ViewSwitcher but this is impractical as the desktop site isn't yet functional.

```
public RedirectResult SwitchView(bool mobile, string returnUrl) {
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == mobile)
        HttpContext.ClearOverriddenBrowser();
    else
        HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(mobile ? BrowserOverride.Mobile : BrowserOverride.Desktop);

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

All of my mobile views are in VIEWNAME.Mobile.cshtml format. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank-you.

Comment: If it's going to be a while before the "desktop" versions are ready, you could always just clone the project, rename the mobile views to remove the `.mobile` part of the name, and deploy that...

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion, although I didn't want to make it a pure mobile project as there is significant work on the desktop version already.
I've just added the view switcher link to all desktop pages for the moment, which works for what I need it for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm maybe a bit late to the party, but I had the same problem like the OP and didn't like Tieson's solution. So I came up with an alternative, that worked great for me.

Add the following code to your projects *Global.asax.cs*:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile);
}
```

This tells ASP.NET on **every** request, that it's a request of a mobile browser.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately I don't need this any more but will remember it for future, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a different tack to try would be to manually specify the mobile views when you return the result from the controller action. `View()` has quite a few overloads (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), one of which lets you specify the view to render: `return View("index.mobile", model)` should work. Once the rest of the app is complete a simple Find+Replace would let you remove the "hack".